# Reading a text file into a 2d array C++

Tags: arrays, file

```
void intializeBoard(char matrix[][arrSize]) {
    char cc = '0';
    char rc = '1';

    for (int r = 0; r < arrSize; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < arrSize; c++) {
            if (r == 0) {
                matrix1[r][c] = cc++;
            }
            else if (c == 0) {
                matrix1[r][c] = rc++;
            }
            else {
                matrix1[r][c] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    matrix1[0][0] = ' ';

    char inputChar;
    ifstream input;

    input.open("project3-allmoves.txt");

    while(!input.eof()){
        for(int row = 1; row < arrSize; row++){
            for(int col = 1; col < arrSize; col++){
                inputChar = input.get();
                matrix1[row][col] = inputChar;
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to read in a file of characters into a 2d array, however it doesn't output anything when i call this function. The array size is 10 and i am filling in column 0 and row 0 with numbers from 1 to 9 and leaving [0][0] blank. This is what the text file looks like:

```
PPCCPCCCP
PPCPCCCPP
PCCPCCCPP
CCPCCPCPC
PCPPPCCCP
PPPPPPCCP
CCCPCPCCP
PCPPCCPPP
PPCCCCPPC
```

And the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

#include "project.h"

using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes
void intializeBoard(char matrix1[][arrSize]);

int main() {
    char board[arrSize][arrSize];
    bool end = false;
    bool gameFinished = false;
    int playersScore = 0;
    int computersScore = 0;
    string move;
    //    srand(time(0));

    displayMessage(1, move);

    intializeBoard(board);

    drawBoard(board);
```

[This is a picture of what the board looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJNGj.png)
 The array size is 10 and i am filling in column 0 and row 0 with numbers from 1 to 9 and leaving [0][0] blank.

Comment: Why would it output anything? It's just putting it into the array you passed in the parameter. Show us the calling code please

Comment: Also, by starting at 1 in both loops you will skip the first index of the matrix, and if `arrSize` is 9 like I presume it would be, then you will read in 8 characters per line and 8 lines, instead of the 9 characters per line and 9 lines. Not to mention that checking for EOF after you close it is a questionable practice. (Maybe you didn't realize that `input.close()` is inside the while loop...)

Comment: @pepperjack Sorry, i've added more information to my code. Also i accidental posted the wrong function originally.

Comment: this is really minimalistic coding... all this code without any comment? Please think of the future you and add some comments in order to enhance readability of your code. what @pepperjack means is that the function does neither return a value nor is any line of code using cout or similar which would generate some "output" that is somehow use or readable not by the user nor any code. What would you like to "output" and where?

Comment: @brownbatman What do you mean by output? There is still nothing there that would output anything. Please give us _all_ the code.

Comment: sorry for not being clearer. I'm calling the drawBoard function from the "project.h" library. That displays the board. The initializeBoard function is supposed to fill the array with the text file. Then the drawBoard will display it .

Comment: thanks @pepperjack. I've gotten it working now.